# How to show elements in a ListView by selecting an item in another ListView?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# project and I have two ListViews and two classes(Bicycle and User) that have a property (Id) in common. I displayed the bicycles in the first ListView and now I want to display the Users in the second one by selecting a bicycle. So if the selected bicycle has Id=1, I want to show the users that also have the Id=1. This is what I tried, but it only shows me one user for id=1, instead of two.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Bicycle> IstBicycles;
    private List<User> IstUsers;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IstBicycles = new List<Bicycle>();
        IstUsers = new List<User>();


    }



    public void showBicycles()
    {


        lvBicycles.Items.Clear();
        foreach(Bicycle bicycle in IstBicycles)
        {
            ListViewItem listViewItem = new ListViewItem(bicycle.IDb.ToString());
            listViewItem.SubItems.Add(bicycle.Name);
            listViewItem.SubItems.Add(bicycle.Km.ToString());
            listViewItem.Tag = bicycle;
            lvBicycles.Items.Add(listViewItem);
        }
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bicycle bicycle1 = new Bicycle(1, "Pegas", 200);
        Bicycle bicycle2 = new Bicycle(2, "BMX", 300);
        IstBicycles.Add(bicycle1);
        IstBicycles.Add(bicycle2);
        showBicycles();
    }



    private void lvBicycles_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        User user1 = new User("Mary", 1, 30);
        User user2 = new User("Dan", 2, 40);
        User user3 = new User("Mike", 1, 10);
        IstUsers.Add(user1);
        IstUsers.Add(user2);
        IstUsers.Add(user3);


        if (lvBicycles.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select a bicycle!");
            return;
        }
        ListViewItem listViewItem = lvBicycles.SelectedItems[0];
        Bicycle bicycle = (Bicycle)listViewItem.Tag;


            foreach (User user in IstUsers)
            {
                if (bicycle.IDb.ToString() == user.ID.ToString())
                {
                    lvUsers.Items.Clear();
                    ListViewItem listViewItem1 = new ListViewItem(user.Name);
                    listViewItem1.SubItems.Add(user.ID.ToString());
                    listViewItem1.SubItems.Add(user.Duration.ToString());
                    listViewItem1.Tag = user;
                    lvUsers.Items.Add(listViewItem1);

                }
            }
        


    }
}

    public class Bicycle
{
    private readonly int idb;
    private string name;
    private int km;

    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
    public int IDb { get => idb; }
    public int Km { get => km; set => km = value; }

    public Bicycle(int idb, string name, int km)
    {
        this.idb = idb;
        this.name = name;
        this.km = km;
    }
}
    public class User
{
    private string name;
    private int id;
    private int duration;

    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
    public int Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
    public int Duration { get => duration; set => duration = value; }

    public User(string name, int id, int duration)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're clearing the user ListView inside the foreach loop. Move `lvUsers.Items.Clear();` to above the foreach and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
private void lvBicycles_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    User user1 = new User("Mary", 1, 30);
    User user2 = new User("Dan", 2, 40);
    User user3 = new User("Mike", 1, 10);
    IstUsers.Add(user1);
    IstUsers.Add(user2);
    IstUsers.Add(user3);

    if (lvBicycles.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Select a bicycle!");
        return;
    }
    ListViewItem listViewItem = lvBicycles.SelectedItems[0];
    Bicycle bicycle = (Bicycle)listViewItem.Tag;

    lvUsers.Items.Clear();

    foreach (User user in IstUsers)
    {
        if (bicycle.IDb.ToString() == user.Id.ToString())
        {                   
            ListViewItem listViewItem1 = new ListViewItem(user.Name);
            listViewItem1.SubItems.Add(user.Id.ToString());
            listViewItem1.SubItems.Add(user.Duration.ToString());
            listViewItem1.Tag = user;
            lvUsers.Items.Add(listViewItem1);

        }
    }
}
```

}